# Is it possible in Keras to have an input_shape of width and height 32x32?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I am using Python with Keras and Tensorflow as backend and I want to use input images as small as possible for my model. 
The VGG19 application says that it [allows input shapes as low as 32](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg19) for width and height. A few weeks ago this minimum value was 48 on Keras website. I used it with 48 without problems. Now, I want to try the 32, but I cannot do it because I get:

```
ValueError: Input size must be at least 48x48; got `input_shape=(32, 32, 3)`
```

I mention that I updated Keras to the version 2.2.2 and I also deleted the weights model file I had for VGG19 (from `~/.keras/models/`). If I put the input_shape to (48, 48, 3), it downloads again the model, otherwise I get the error mentioned above.

In short, my code wants to just load the pre-trained model:

```
vgg_conv = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
```

Any idea to follow is appreciated.

Comment: VGG uses max pooling , so it has to have a certain input size , else by the final layer you will end up with no pixels.

Comment: You mean that certain input size should be at least 48 and not get as low as to 32? I just took this 32 value from the  Keras Documentation.

Comment: You can get around of this restriction by creating a new model without or with fewer pooling (downsampling) layers, and copy the pretrained weights to your new model.

Comment: @user36624: Thanks, that is a good work-around.

Comment: @dennlinger: "input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top is False (otherwise the input shape has to be  (224, 224, 3) (with 'channels_last' data format) or (3, 224, 224) (with 'channels_first' data format). It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 32. "